# Doctrine 2 overriding many to one association

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, sylius

Is it possible to override `@ManyToOne(targetEntity)`?

I read [this Doctrine documentation page](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/override-field-association-mappings-in-subclasses.html), but it doesn't mention how to override `targetEntity`.

Here's my code:

```php
namespace AppBundle\Model\Order\Entity;

use AppBundle\Model\Base\Entity\Identifier;
use AppBundle\Model\Base\Entity\Product;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\AttributeOverrides;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\AttributeOverride;

/**
 * Class OrderItem
 *
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="sylius_order_item")
 * @ORM\AssociationOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AssociationOverride(
 *          name="variant",
 *          joinColumns=@ORM\JoinColumn(
 *              name="variant", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
 */
class OrderItem extends \Sylius\Component\Core\Model\OrderItem
{

    /**
     * @var
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Model\Base\Entity\Product")
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $product
     */
    public function setProduct($product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }
}
```

I was able to to override the definition for the "variant" column and set this column to null, but I can't figure it out how to change the `targetEntity`.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the doc, you cannot change the type of your association:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#association-override

BUT, you can define a targetEntity as an interface (that's the default sylius conf it seems),

```
targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ProductInterface"
```

Extends the original one in your Interface file

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;    
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ProductInterface as BaseProductInterface;
interface ProductInterface extends BaseProductInterface {}
```

And add the mapping in your configuration

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        resolve_target_entities:
            AppBundle\Entity\ProductInterface: AppBundle\Entity\Product
```

It's described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to override the `targetEntity` value of an association when using annotations, but it is possible when using PHP mapping (`php` or `staticphp` in Symfony).

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/php-mapping.html

We can create a function:

```
function updateAssociationTargetEntity(ClassMetadata $metadata, $association, $targetEntity)
{
    if (!isset($metadata->associationMappings[$association])) {
        throw new \LogicException("Association $association not defined on $metadata->name");
    }
    $metadata->associationMappings[$association]['targetEntity'] = $targetEntity;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
updateAssociationTargetEntity($metadata, 'product', AppBundle\Model\Base\Entity\Product::class);
```

That way, when Doctrine loads the metadata for the class `AppBundle\Model\Order\Entity\OrderItem`, it first loads the parent (`\Sylius\Component\Core\Model\OrderItem`) metadata, and then it loads the PHP mapping for the child class where we override the association mapping that was set when loading the parent class metadata.